# WPF - How to stop a TabControl changing indices in a MouseUp event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TabControl with an ItemsSource of multiple TabItems, and an additional TabItem that adds new TabItems to this list. The TabItem responsible for adding an item listens to the MouseUp event.
The problem is, that after adding an item I update the SelectedIndex, but then the SelectedIndex changes to the element I've clicked on.

Part of the XAML:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
```

My code:

```
public ObservableCollection<TabItem> Tabs { get; set; }
public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }

private void Tab_add_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    int count = Tabs.Count;
    TabItem tabItem = new TabItemDepartment("Header #x");
    Tabs.Insert(count - 1, tabItem);
    SelectedIndex = count - 2;
}
```

edit: Final code (only relevant parts) based on answers:

```
public class CalendarViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<TabItem> Tabs { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _SelectedIndex;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            _SelectedIndex = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedIndex));
        }
    }

    private void Tab_add_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem tabItem = new TabItemDepartment("Header #x");
        Tabs.Insert(Tabs.Count - 1, tabItem);
        SelectedIndex = Tabs.Count - 2;
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try doing it in preview mousedown event, if `e.Handled` stops the event from routing down, then it should work.

Comment: That works, but it doesn't change the  SelectedIndex. So the index stays the same when I click on the add tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use either `DependencyProperty`, or `INotifyPropertyChanged`, because the binding engine is not aware of the changes of `SelectedIndex` property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedIndexProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedIndex",
    typeof(int),
    typeof(WhateverYourClassNameIs));

public int SelectedIndex
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value); }
}
```

Alternatively, you can make this class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but generally for classes that already derive from `FrameworkElement` (classes with UI), `DependencyProperty` would be preferred.

Comment: So I have to change my ViewModel to `public class CalendarViewModel : DependencyObject` (this is where the eventhandler is defined and registered), and change the `typeof` to `typeof(CalendarViewModel)`? I tried this, but it still won't update the index.

Comment: If you are already using MVVM, then use INotifyPropertyChanged. There are tons of examples on the net for that. @Johannes

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues here:

1. `SelectedIndex` does need to either be a `DependencyProperty` or your class with `SelectedIndex` defined needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Try this:

```
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedIndexProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedIndex", typeof(int), typeof(YOURCLASS), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

2. Your logic in the mouse up event is wrong. I assume you only want to add a tab if the last item is clicked? Also you cannot use your local count variable because the number of items in the collection changes once you add your new tab.

Try this:

```
private void Tab_add_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    // Only add if the user clicks on the last items.
    if (this.SelectedIndex == this.Tabs.Count - 1)
    {
        TabItem tabItem = new TabItemDepartment("Header #x");
        this.Tabs.Insert(this.Tabs.Count - 1, tabItem);
        // The Count has changed at this point so make sure we check the collection again.
        this.SelectedIndex = this.Tabs.Count - 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, I was reworking the code and forgot to change the code for the Count - since it didn't work in the first place I was overlooking this mistake.
I tried using a DependencyProperty but it didn't work so I opted for `INotifyPropertyChanged` which did work.